# Vertically align span in a tag

Tags: html, css, xhtml

So here is my markup.  Solution has to work dynamically for a single line or double line in the span.  So it should be css that can be added to each of these and work fine.  From looking on the internez this seems to be impossible.  Please prove me wrong.

```
<ul style="text-align:center; list-style-type: none;">
    <li style="width: 200px">
        <a href="http://www.bing.com" style="display: block; height:35px; background: Black;">
            <span>Vertical Align This Text</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul style="text-align:center; list-style-type: none;">
    <li style="width: 200px">
        <a href="http://www.bing.com" style="display: block; height:35px; background: Black;">
            <span>Vertical Align This Text With Double Line As Well</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your containing `<a>` have a set `height` value, you can use the ol' `line-height`trick of setting it to the same value, in this case:

```
a { 
    height:35px; 
    line-height:35px; 
}
```

This will only work, though, if your `<span>` isn't wider than your `<li>`. In the case with the double line, you'd need to set the `<line-height>` to half the `<a>`'s height (**35px** height divided by **2** lines), so around 17px. If you had three lines, it would work with **35px/3** ~ 11px. But as you can imagine, it will look smooshed at one point.
So depending on the content you might have to with the relative/absolute positioning, a smaller font, or just less content ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comment but i don't have the necessary info at rendering time to know if it is 1 or 2 lines.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
<ul style="text-align:center; list-style-type: none;">
    <li style="width: 200px; display: table">
        <a href="http://www.bing.com" style="display: table-cell; height:35px; background: Black; vertical-align: middle; text-align:center">
            <span>Vertical Align This Text</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul style="text-align:center; list-style-type: none;">
    <li style="width: 200px; display: table">
        <a href="http://www.bing.com" style="display: table-cell; height:35px; background: Black; vertical-align: middle; text-align:center">
            <span>Vertical Align This Text With Double Line As Well</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS code for convenience:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  width: 200px;
  display: table;
}

a {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 35px;
  background: black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: **[Note](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp)**: Internet Explorer 8 (and higher) supports the property values "inline-table", "run-in", **"table"**, "table-caption", **"table-cell"**, "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", "table-row-group", and "inherit" only if a !DOCTYPE is specified.

Comment: This will work for IE8 and above as previously stated.  For IE 6 & 7 you will need to create two nested spans/divs the outer with margin-top: 50% and inner with top: -50%

Comment: So weird, i swear our projects are exactly the same but for some reason my heighth and width is not getting set.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `<li>` and `<a>` the following CSS properties

```
li{
  position:relative;
}

a{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-17px; /*negative half of your <a> tag height */
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/r4Wsx/

Comment: I think you meant `position: relative;` for the `li`.